# How to update the button text in a flutter alert box

Tags: flutter

I have an alert box in flutter that prompts the user for a name and date. The name is a simple TextField and the date is entered by clicking a button to open a date picker. Initially the button has the current date as the text.I would like this to be updated by the selected date, but can't get it to happen. It does get updated when I go back the to text input though.

Thanks for any help

My current code looks like this.

```dart
Future<bool> getNameDate(BuildContext context)
  async
  {
    return showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Save Event"),
          content: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Event Name"
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    name = value;
                  },
                  onSubmitted: (value) {
                  },
                ),
              ),
              new Expanded(
                  child: new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text("Date of Event "),
                      new RaisedButton(
                          child: Text(DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(when)),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
                              context: context,
                              initialDate: when,
                              firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
                              lastDate: DateTime(2101),
                            );
                            setState(() {
                              when = picked ;
                            });
                          }),
                    ],
                  )
              )
            ],
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
                child: const Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                }),
            new FlatButton(
                child: const Text("CANCEL"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                }),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Sorry about the comment. It would be nice if it were possible to reply to answers in a better fashion. Anyway, I had hoped I could create a more generic "Stateful dialog" So I created something like this..

```dart
class StateDialog extends StatefulWidget
{
  final AlertDialog dialog;
  StateDialog({Key key, @required this.dialog}) : super (key: key);

  @override
  StateDialogState createState() => StateDialogState(dialog: dialog);

}

class StateDialogState extends State<StateDialog>
{
  final AlertDialog dialog;
  StateDialogState({@required this.dialog});
  @override
  Widget build(_) {
    return dialog;
  }
}
```

Then in my existing function changed it to..

```dart
    return showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context)
      {
        return StateDialog(dialog: AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Save Event"),
          content: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
etc...
```

But this still doesn't update the text in the date button. I would be nice to understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the `setState()` method actually isn't updating the `alertDialog` but rather the widget up the tree. The `alertDialog` doesn't have its own state. You can check out [this article](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/05/hint-5-how-to-refresh-the-content-of-a-dialog-via-setstate/) and if you want here's a code example that you can change a bit to suit your need:

Try this: I tested it and upon picking a new date the button's text is updated with the correct date you just picked!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("StackoverFlow"),
      ),
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await _dialogCall(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _dialogCall(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return MyDialog();
        });
  }
}

class MyDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyDialogState createState() => new _MyDialogState();
}

class _MyDialogState extends State<MyDialog> {
  String name = "";
  bool button = false;
  DateTime when = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Save Event"),
      content: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: new TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "Event Name"),
              onChanged: (value) {
                name = value;
              },
              onSubmitted: (value) {},
            ),
          ),
          new Expanded(
              child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text("Date of Event "),
              new RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(when)),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
                      context: context,
                      initialDate: when,
                      firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
                      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
                    );
                    setState(() {
                      when = picked;
                    });
                  }),
            ],
          ))
        ],
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
            child: const Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            }),
        new FlatButton(
            child: const Text("CANCEL"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
            }),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<bool> getNameDate(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Save Event"),
          content: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "Event Name"),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    name = value;
                  },
                  onSubmitted: (value) {},
                ),
              ),
              new Expanded(
                  child: new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text("Date of Event "),
                  new RaisedButton(
                      child: Text(DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(when)),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
                          context: context,
                          initialDate: when,
                          firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
                          lastDate: DateTime(2101),
                        );
                        setState(() {
                          when = picked;
                        });
                      }),
                ],
              ))
            ],
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
                child: const Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                }),
            new FlatButton(
                child: const Text("CANCEL"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                }),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can make something like this work, but I tried creating a class to do this `class StateDialog extends StatefulWidget
{
  final AlertDialog dialog;
  StateDialog({Key key, @required this.dialog}) : super (key: key);

  @override
  StateDialogState createState() => StateDialogState(dialog: dialog);

}

class StateDialogState extends State<StateDialog>
{
  final AlertDialog dialog;
  StateDialogState({@required this.dialog});
  @override
  Widget build(_) {
    return dialog;
  }
}` But couldn't make it work. Do you know why?

Comment: Posting this in a comment make it very hard to read. can you please edit your question and add what you attempted? Thx!

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated the original question

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the format i provided before you do it in your format? I'm not sure if it is the cause but i don't see a reason for it not to work. Please do try it in the format i provided (Have the alert dialog constructed inside your dialogClass rather than passing an alert dialog) and if that didn't work let me know.

Comment: Sorry I probably didn't make myself clear. I did say in my original comment that I can make your original solution work. I was trying to make a more general solution where I could make any AlertDialog "stateful" by wrapping it in my StateDialog class. But I can't seem to make that work. It would be nice to know why it doesn't work. Otherwise I will stick with your original solution. Thanks

Comment: I believe, and i could be COMPLETELY wrong here but it's probably because the variables were not defined in the dialog's state and so when you setState they're not affected as you as technically just passing an alert dialog to a stateful widget that essentially has nothing stored in its state other than the dialog itself. something like that i guess. Hope my answer helped you with the problem though! Glad it worked